# unable to install ggpubr. tried other solutions but does not work

Tags: r, ggpubr

I am having trouble installing this package "ggpubr". it seems to me that this is a common problem. I tried to find the solution here on stackoverflow but nothing worked so far!
i tried to install it. it shows

```
> library(rstatix)
Error in library(rstatix) : there is no package called ‘rstatix’
> library(broom)
Error in library(broom) : there is no package called ‘broom’
> library(ggpubr)
Error in library(ggpubr) : there is no package called ‘ggpubr’
> install.packages("ggpubr")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:.....win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘rlang’, ‘tidyselect’, ‘vctrs’, ‘dplyr’, ‘broom’, ‘rstatix’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
           binary source needs_compilation
rlang       0.4.5 0.4.10              TRUE
tidyselect  1.0.0  1.1.0              TRUE
vctrs       0.2.4  0.3.6              TRUE
dplyr       0.8.5  1.0.4              TRUE
broom       0.5.6  0.7.4             FALSE
rstatix     0.4.0  0.6.0             FALSE
ggpubr      0.2.5  0.4.0             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/rlang_0.4.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1115838 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/tidyselect_1.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 242507 bytes (236 KB)
downloaded 236 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/vctrs_0.2.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1018801 bytes (994 KB)
downloaded 994 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/dplyr_0.8.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3256479 bytes (3.1 MB)
downloaded 3.1 MB

package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘tidyselect’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\....\downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘broom’, ‘rstatix’, ‘ggpubr’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/broom_0.7.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 629713 bytes (614 KB)
downloaded 614 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rstatix_0.6.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 394803 bytes (385 KB)
downloaded 385 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggpubr_0.4.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2689307 bytes (2.6 MB)
downloaded 2.6 MB

* installing *source* package 'broom' ...
** package 'broom' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'dplyr' 0.8.5 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'broom'
* removing 'C:win-library/3.5/broom'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'broom' is not available for package 'rstatix'
* removing 'C:/win-library/3.5/rstatix'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rstatix’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'rstatix' is not available for package 'ggpubr'
* removing 'C:/win-library/3.5/ggpubr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggpubr’ had non-zero exit status
```

but when i load the package it says

"Error in library(ggpubr) : there is no package called ‘ggpubr’"

but i already installed it along with "broom" "rstatix"

Comment: It seems that you are using a very old version of R (v3.5). Update it, then try again.

Comment: it worked! thank you so much. this software is unnecessarily complicated. I have checked that my software Rstudio is up to date, i thought that is enough. so i didn't know that i have to update R as well. 
but thanks it solved the problem

Comment: RStudio is just a very fancy text editor to help your usage of R. R is the engine that actually runs everything.